# Android Paging 3 remoteMediator infinitely load(APPEND) data with Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-paging

I'm trying to implement a list with Paging 3 library using RemoteMediator.
Initial loading is OK. Mediator loaded only 3 pages, which is set in 'PageConfig'. In my case, there are 10 data per page.
But when scroll the list to trigger extra loading for more data, then Mediator starts loading data infinitely until it returns `MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)` (Which means all data in remote was loaded). Even though scrolling is stopped.
I have no idea what makes Mediator keep loading.
I want Mediator to load data only needed along scrolling.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class PostRemoteMediator(
    private val postApi: ApiInterface,
    private val database: PostDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int, Post>() {

    override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, Post>): MediatorResult {
        return try {
            val userId = when (loadType) {
                LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                    logd(">> loadType.REFRESH")
                    STARTING_USER_ID
                }
                LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                }
                LoadType.APPEND -> {
                    logd(">> loadType.APPEND")

                    val lastItem = state.lastItemOrNull()
                        ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)

                    lastItem.userId + 1
                }
            }

            logd(">> load data with userId = $userId")
            val response = postApi.getUserPosts(userId)

            database.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    database.postsDao().clearAll()
                }

                database.postsDao().insertAll(response?.body() ?: emptyList())
            }

            MediatorResult.Success(
                endOfPaginationReached = response.body().isNullOrEmpty()
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class PostRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteApi: ApiInterface,
    private val database: PostDatabase
) : PostRepository {
    override fun getUserPosts(): Flow<PagingData<Post>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 1
            ),
            remoteMediator = PostRemoteMediator(
                remoteApi,
                database
            )
        ) {
            // returns all data in table as PagingSource<Int, Post>
            database.postsDao().getPosts()
        }.flow
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class PostViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val postRepository: PostRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val TAG = PostViewModel::class.simpleName

    val postFlow: Flow<PagingData<Post>> = postRepository.getUserPosts().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

This is UI code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PostList(postsFlow: Flow<PagingData<Post>>) {
    val posts = postsFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)) {
        items(posts, key = { it.id }) { post ->
            post?.also { PostItem(userId = it.userId, id = it.id, content = it.body) }
        }

        posts.apply {
            when {
                loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    item { LoadingView(modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxSize()) }
                }
                loadState.mediator?.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    item { LoadingView(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()) }
                }
                loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
                    val error = loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
                    item { ErrorView(error.error.localizedMessage!!, modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxSize()) { retry() } }
                }
                loadState.mediator?.append is LoadState.Error -> {
                    val error = loadState.append as LoadState.Error
                    item { ErrorView(error.error.localizedMessage!!, modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()) { retry() } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any answer

Comment: hey did you solve it ? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @SaneenKP haven't solved :(

Comment: How could the problem be exactly the same . I have been working on it for the past 2 weeks , I cant seem to figure it out :{

Comment: @SaneenKP Me neither... I guess it is Mediator its own problem, or triggered infinite loading by detecting bottom of the list at a moment while LazyColumn updated when a new data list provided. Because I can see the flickering looks like scroll up and down quickly. This is all I can think.

Comment: wow u thought  so much . I thought my android studio was broken.

Comment: @heeeeee still not solved? facing the same issue

Comment: @UdiOshi It wasn't sloved.. Actually, I've stopped this project.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the pageSize when creating the PageConfig.

According to the documentation:

> Should be several times the number of visible items onscreen.
> Configuring your page size depends on how your data is being loaded and used. Smaller page sizes improve memory usage, latency, and avoid GC churn. Larger pages generally improve loading throughput, to a point (avoid loading more than 2MB from SQLite at once, since it incurs extra cost).
> If you're loading data for very large, social-media style cards that take up most of a screen, and your database isn't a bottleneck, 10-20 may make sense. If you're displaying dozens of items in a tiled grid, which can present items during a scroll much more quickly, consider closer to 100.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure the initialLoadSize is less then pageSize that using in remoteMediator , and using larg number when u assign it to pageSize depend on how data u have , in my case i use 15 pagesize cause i have 75 item in my pager ,
second using this way to display item in lazy column its work with me,

```
        items(animePagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
        val anime= animePagingItems[index]
        if (anime != null) {
            ItemAnime(animeData= anime) {}
        }
    }
```